# issue with horizontal scrolling div using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, horizontal-scrolling

I am using **flexbox css** to make a container with number of divs to scroll horizontally but the problem is when I try to add more divs to the container, it moves to the left side and the divs left to the display are hidden.

I don't understand what's happening
here is the code snippet and [codepen](https://codepen.io/avreddy/pen/QaQGJv)

```css
.scroll{
  display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}
.item{
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: #e4e4e4;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="item">
  </div>
   <div class="item">
  </div> <div class="item">
  </div> <div class="item">
  </div> <div class="item">
  </div> <div class="item">
  </div>
   <div class="item">
  </div> <div class="item">
  </div>
   <div class="item">
  </div> <div class="item">
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main issue here is that for some `justify-content` values, the overflow distribution will overflow the flex parent at both its left and right edge.

- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#distribution-values

Therefor a new keyword has been introduced, `safe`, where one can control how that overflow should behave.

- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#overflow-values

As this is a quite new addition to the Flexbox model, it won't work cross browsers yet, nor does `space-evenly`.

When it does (and for browsers that support it), this CSS line will fix the issue

```
justify-content: space-evenly safe;
```

---

A possible workaround, to achieve both evenly spaced items when they won't fill their parent, and only overflow at the right edge when too many, could be to use auto margins.

Stack snippet

```css
.scroll{
  display: flex;
  /*flex-wrap: nowrap;                   this is the default, can be removed  */ 
   overflow-x: auto;
  /*justify-content: space-evenly;       removed  */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}
.item{
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: #e4e4e4;
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.item{
  margin-left: auto;                  /* added  */
}
.item:last-child{
  margin-right: auto;                 /* added  */
}
```

```html
Too many
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<br>Too few
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `justify-content: space-evenly;` from `.scroll`.

**Demo:**

```css
.scroll{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}
.item{
    flex:  0 0 auto;
    background: #e4e4e4;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="item">
  </div><div class="item">
  </div><div class="item">
  </div><div class="item">
  </div><div class="item">
  </div><div class="item">
  </div><div class="item">
  </div><div class="item">
  </div><div class="item">
  </div><div class="item">
  </div><div class="item">
  </div><div class="item">
  </div><div class="item">
  </div><div class="item">
  </div><div class="item">
  </div><div class="item">
  </div>
</div>
```

This will stop the elements from being out of bounds on both sides. 
All `div`'s get displayed in a row this way.

Comment: i kept `justify-contet` as per my requirement only you can't simply say to remove it, if you say to remove it you have to give proper explanation and alternate check other answers

Answer (score 0):

```
.Wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: auto;
  max-width: 100%; //this will solve issue
}

.TagWrapper:{
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position of the Parent or Container to be **Relative** and the child inside them to be **absolute**.

```
.Parent{
display: flex;
// and use any flexbox property
width: 100%;
height: 100%


position: relative; // important point
overflow: auto;
}

.Child{
position: absolute; // important point
}
```